# What is the opposite of "to stink" (v)? Is there one at all?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Specifically I'm looking for an antonym of the infinitive rather than the noun. For example, "fragrance" is an antonym of "stink" (the noun), but you can't say "Wow, that fragrants" or "Wow that fragrances" in the way you can say "Wow that stinks".

Comment: I like this question.  Would you consider "Wow, that is fragrant!" (or something similar) or are you sure that you want a verb?

Comment: "smell like a rose" is an antonym to two meanings of "to stink"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's a single verb available in English which is the exact opposite of "To stink". With exact opposite I mean as in that it can be used the same way with opposed-meaning sentences (like "*I love you*" vs "*I hate you*").

On my NOAD I found this example "**That's a lovely scent you're wearing**". There is also the expression "**to smell good**", although I guess (since I'm not a native speaker)  they may not fit all situations and contexts, as in formal/informal, so about this I'd like some native speaker to give contribution.

Finally, I found [to perfume](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/perfume_2), which means *"to make the air in a place smell pleasant*", but I didn't suggest this one because it's especially used with flowers as in "*The garden was perfumed with the smell of roses.*"

If I find more, I'll make sure to include it.

Comment: +1, although I don't think perfume fits the bill exactly. The OP, for example, wouldn't be able to say "Wow, that perfumes!" I think you're right about there not being a single word alternative.

Comment: "Wow, that smells good!" is the closest you're gonna get to the direct antonym of "Wow, that stinks!"

Comment: Also, "to smell good" is actually slightly more formal than "to stink". In a truly formal context, you'd use "to smell bad" instead of "to stink".

Comment: *To smell as fresh as a daisy*, perhaps?

Comment: @Andy F: I just mentioned it in order to give a better answer, but as you can see, I excluded it, I thought it was clear, but if it isn't maybe I should edit... @Martha: Thanks. :)

Comment: @Alenanno, I don't think it makes your answer unclear, so I think you can leave it in.

Comment: I'd suggest "Wow, that is redolent!" as the direct antonym of "Wow, that stinks!" as having approximately the same uh, oomph.

Comment: @Kit: I saw it but my dictionary (NOAD) says this: "archaic or poetic/literary fragrant or sweet-smelling: a rich, inky, redolent wine."

Comment: @Alenanno **WHAAAAT!?** ***Archaic!*** ***Poetic!*** I can't believe it! I guess I need to stop reading so much and start paying attention to the real world.

Comment: @Kit: The [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/redolent) gives it only as literary, not mentioning archaic, but still... :P

Comment: @Kit: keep reading.  It's the readers who keep the useful and beautiful words from succumbing to newspeak alternatives.

Comment: @PSU UR 2late. Reading stinx!

Comment: @Kit: Or, obviously, 133t2p3@k (if that's how one "spells" leetspeak in, uh, leetspeakish).

Comment: +1 because "To perfume" would be the opposite of to stink when used as a verb. "To perfume" is "to impregnate with a sweet scent". It's just that people rarely use perfume as a verb so it sounds foreign when used as such.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a single English verb meaning *to give off a pleasant fragrance* in common parlance. This may be partly because of vagueness surrounding the word *smell* itself, which is of unknown origin.

Unless modified by a *positive* adjective, the default meaning as both verb and noun is invariably negative. The unmodified "**You smell**" *always* implies "bad". So even though you might think there's an intransitive verb *to smell* meaning *to give off a (good / bad / neutral) aroma*, that's not really true. The core meaning is negative - it's just that you can reverse it with positive modifiers.

The standard expressions are **smell nice**, **be fragrant**, etc. Any single word would be at the very least uncommon and potentially unfamiliar to the hearer. So I think even if there was such a word, I at least would be wary of using it lest the negative connotations from the associated usage of *smell* caused my intended compliment to backfire.