# A positive alternative to "smelling" to describe something with a pleasant odor

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

When one hears that something *smells*, one would generally assume that it smells bad.

Isn't there a word which wouldn't bring to mind the idea of a bad odor? For example, how would you describe *pot-pourri* (assuming you like the smell of pot-pourri)? If possible, I would like an adjective, or a word that could takes the place of an adjective.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the opposite of "to stink" (v)? Is there one at all?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/what-is-the-opposite-of-to-stink-v-is-there-one-at-all)

Comment: @Kitḫ not entirely, the post you link is about searching a verb, whereas I am searching for an adjective. They are related, but I don't think they are duplicates.

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/ende?search=duften

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about *fragrant* or *scented*?  Or you could try *sweet-smelling*, *floral* or something else referring to the specific scent.

Answer (score 17):

How about using the word ***aromatic***?

Comment: Make sure there are no chemists in the audience if you use aromatic. Some of the aromatic compounds are not fragrant at all.

Answer (score 11):

Fragrant.

> **fra·grant** /ˈfrāgrənt/ Adjective: Having a pleasant or sweet smell.