# Word for “good smell”

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A positive alternative to “smelling” to describe something with a pleasant odor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42090/a-positive-alternative-to-smelling-to-describe-something-with-a-pleasant-odor)

What do you call a smell that is good? I've been wondering this question since childhood.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A positive alternative to "smelling" to describe something with a pleasant odor](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42090/a-positive-alternative-to-smelling-to-describe-something-with-a-pleasant-odor) | Also, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/what-is-the-opposite-of-to-stink-v-is-there-one-at-all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with tchrist, but I also think of a good smell, such as bread baking, as an *aroma*.

There is also [*redolence*,](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/redolence) which is defined as:

> pleasant odor; fragrance

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with aroma and fragrance as the best two choices, but for added variety, here are a couple more:

- perfume, especially in the verb sense of 'to impart a pleasant smell'
- scent, which is often used objectively, but (especially as an adjective - a
  scented kerchief) can also connote a pleasant smell.