# The Case of the Missing Verb, or can a perfectly good word fail to exist?

Tags: verbs

Is it possible for an action to lack a verb?  For example - to answer my own question - there is a verb for smell bad ("stink"), but there is no counterpart for to smell good.  Is there?

Comment: I'm not sure very many of these "potentially perfectly good words" actually exist. Offhand I can't think of one-word equivalents for *sound/look/taste/feel pleasant* either.

Comment: Yep!  Plenty of words don't exist.  You can always make them up, if you like.

Comment: Why should there be such a word? There's an expression for it that you can expand, and people tend to prefer hearing at length about good smells, rather than bad ones, for which a single word suffices.

Comment: Hm. This starts off as a rhetorical question, and ends up as a duplicate. [What is the opposite of “to stink” (v)? Is there one at all?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/what-is-the-opposite-of-to-stink-v-is-there-one-at-all) [A positive alternative to “smelling” to describe something with a pleasant odor](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42090/a-positive-alternative-to-smelling-to-describe-something-with-a-pleasant-odor), [Word for “good smell”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102953/word-for-good-smell).

Answer (score 0):

[*"Perfume"*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfume) is a verb that works for many good smells, and not just scents that you'd wear as perfume. When you search for *"perfumed with the scent of …"* on Google, you come up with *"baked goods"*, *"pine"*, *"ripening fruit"* …

On the other hand, you wouldn't smell something and say *"that really perfumes"*.

Answer (score 0):

I think "redolate" (verb) would do well to convey this meaning ("to smell good"). To my knowledge, redolate is not currently a word.

Comment: *A giant white head grows during the pour and lingers afterward. Smell is of oranges, spicy earth and moss, and alcohol. Taste is exceptionally dry for a 9% ABV beer, with delicious Cheerios base malt and subtle Belgian earthiness. Saaz and Amarillo make a **redolate** combination that reminds one of a citrus garden: vegetative and earthy smells mixed with a sweet orange perfume.*; *When plants grow over my dust, let every leaf **redolate** with the aroma of my fidelity to you.*; ...

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to EL&U. Thanks for your input!

Comment: "the film seems to really redolate with a sense of subdued quietude." The meaning is clearly unfixed.